# Suppress $type at the creation of the JsonObjectContract

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net, signalr

I'm trying to force the suppression of a few specific $type outputs (while keeping others) in Json.NET. They are unnecessary in my application. The Json.NET source code shows this:

```
private bool ShouldWriteType(...)
{
  TypeNameHandling resolvedTypeNameHandling =
    ((member != null) ? member.TypeNameHandling : null)
    ?? ((containerProperty != null) ? containerProperty.ItemTypeNameHandling : null)
    ?? ((containerContract != null) ? containerContract.ItemTypeNameHandling : null)
    ?? Serializer._typeNameHandling;
```

which made me think that I could override the serializer settings by setting the `ItemTypeNameHandling` in the container contract. Alas, it doesn't work with arrays. I tried overriding the method to get array contracts, but the setting there affects every item in the array. That's not what I want. (And SignalR sends all the method parameters in an object array.) Here is my full demo code where I was trying to figure out how to keep the type of `A` in the output but suppress the type of `B` (and all `sealed` classes). How do I override the contract resolver to do this properly?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace DemoBadTypeInclusion
{
    class A { public int P1 { get; set; } }

    // this attribute doesn't work and I don't want to have to reference Json.NET in my POCO
    //[JsonObject(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]
    sealed class B { public int P2 { get; set; } }

    internal class DtoContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
        {
            var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
            if (objectType.IsSealed && objectType.BaseType == typeof(object))
            {
                contract.ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
            }
            return contract;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var objs = new object[] {new A {P1 = 3}, new B {P2 = 4}};

            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
                ContractResolver = new DtoContractResolver(),
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs, settings);
            Console.WriteLine(json);

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Update: after studying the Json.NET code more, it appears that this line from `SerializeList` is the source of my trouble:

```
JsonContract valueContract = contract.FinalItemContract ?? GetContractSafe(value);
```

I want the fallback value (`GetContractSafe`). Does anyone know how to make `FinalItemContract` null?

Comment: FYI http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: Reposted here: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you suppress one type reference of the object Array, you will make the hole Array undeserializable.
So you possibly can suppress all type references of the Array.

To suppress only the type references of Arrays of object

```
protected override JsonArrayContract CreateArrayContract(Type objectType)
{
            var c = base.CreateArrayContract(objectType);

            if(objectType == typeof(Object[]))
                c.ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;

            return c;
}
```

If you dont need deserialization back to the original objects, just set

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
  TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
  ...
};
```

I know that it is not an exact answer, but I see no use
components to identify some of the elements of object arrays with types for deserializing.
And so i think, thats why it is not supported by json.net

After all here is a workaround, that suppresses only one type:

```
static void Main()
        {
            var objs = new object[] { new A { P1 = 3 }, new B { P2 = 4 } };

            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
                ContractResolver = new DtoContractResolver(),
            };


            var serial = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

            var jsonArray = new JArray();


            foreach (var obj in objs)
            {
                if (obj != null && obj.GetType().IsSealed && obj.GetType().BaseType == typeof(object))
                    serial.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
                else
                    serial.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;

                jsonArray.Add(JObject.FromObject(obj, serial));
            }

            var json = jsonArray.ToString(Formatting.None);
            Console.WriteLine(json);

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Your very first suggestion seems to be the right answer. I tried inverting it such that I only set the type name handling on objects where I want to use the type. However, that appears to not work as the type handling is pulled from the parent object rather than the current object.